# How to prevent conflicts on components when using GSAP in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I am using GSAP and Lenis to make the web.

There are two components, `Part1` and `Part2`, and `Part2` is seen before the `tl1` timeline of GSAP applied in `Part1` is finished.

Maybe it's a problem caused by a collision between the rendering of the components and the GSAP used in *useEffect*.

It seems like a common problem when using React and GSAP together, how do you all solve it??

**App.jsx:**

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    smooth();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Wrap>
        <Nav />
        <Part1 />
        <Part2 />
      </Wrap>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Part1.jsx:**

```
function Part1() {
  const rows = [
    [Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4],
    [Image5, Image6, Image7, Image8],
    [Image9, Image10, Image11, Image12],
    [Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4],
    [Image5, Image6, Image7, Image8],
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      var tl1 = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".part-1",
          start: "50% 50%",
          end: "250% 50%",
          scrub: true,
          markers: true,
          pin: true,
        },
      });

      tl1
        .to(".rotate-div", { rotate: -15, scale: 0.8 }, "a")
        .to(".row-div-1", { marginTop: "5%" }, "a")
        .to(".row-div-2", { marginTop: "-2%" }, "a")
        .to(".row-div-3", { marginTop: "-8%" }, "a")
        .to(".row-div-4", { marginTop: "-10%" }, "a")
        .to(".overlay-div h1", { opacity: 1, delay: 0.2 }, "a")
        .to(".overlay-div", { backgroundColor: "#000000b4" }, "a")
        .to(".scrolling", { width: "100%" }, "a");
    });

    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrap className="part1">
      <div className="content-part-1">
        <div className="rotate-div">
          {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <div key={rowIndex} className={`row-div row-div-${rowIndex}`}>
              {row.map((img, imgIndex) => (
                <div key={imgIndex} className="img-div">
                  <img src={img} alt={`Image ${rowIndex * 4 + imgIndex + 1}`} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-div">
          <h1>Monta</h1>
          <div className="scroll-down">
            <h3>SCROLL DOWN</h3>
            <div className="scroll-p">
              <div className="scrolling" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

export default Part1;
```

**Part2.jsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Wrap } from "./Part2Style";
import { gsap, ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/all";

const Part2 = () => {
  const text = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit", "mollitia iure dolor digmos."];

  return (
    <Wrap className="part-2">
      <div className="rounded-div-wrapper">
        <div className="rounded-div"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="content-2">
        <div className="text-area">
          <h1>{text[0]}</h1>
          <br />
          <h2>{text[1]}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="text-area-hover">
          <h1>{text[0]}</h1>
          <br />
          <h2>{text[1]}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
};

export default Part2;
```

CodeSandBox : [React](https://codesandbox.io/s/brandbeet-flk7py?resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800)